# Is there a way to send prompts to a netcat server Dynamically by scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I am given a problem by my professor to design a script for netcat prompts.. I need to calculate the sum of given two numbers and pass the sum as prompt for 1000 times. I developed a script using awk to get the requried numbers but don't know how to pass or echo that to nc server.

```
Welcome to the Ultimate Math Contest!!
Solve 1000 quick math problems to complete
You have 10 second for each problem.
What is the sum of 89187 + 26971:
You have 5 seconds to type in your stuff...
Exit...
116158
```

What i need is instead of typing the sum after the connection is closed it needs to dynamically type the sum for 1000 times. instead of exiting and then echoing the sum.

CODE

```
#!/bin/bash
extract_numbers(){
numbers=($(echo "$output" | awk 'NR==4 {gsub(/[^0-9]+/, " "); var1=$1; var2=$2; print var1, var2}'))
number1=${numbers[0]}
number2=${numbers[1]}
sum=$((number1 + number2))
echo $sum
}
output=$(echo "" | nc 65.2.97.115 8003)
echo "$output"
result=$(extract_numbers "$output")
echo $result
```

I tried echoing the sum and also wrapped it in a function but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: you can use tools like [tag:expect] (for Tcl) or [tag:pexpect] (for Python). or you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you prefer shell scripts.

Comment: i tried pexpect but it's not working

Comment: Just "it's not working" cannot help others help you. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [repro].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need something like this, send data via `nc`:

```
nc -q0 $address $port <<< "$data"
```

And receive something via `nc`:

```
result=$(nc -l -p $sport)
echo $result
```